# Anaconda doesn't show me the packages that are conflicting

Tags: python, conda

I have recently noticed that I had some stale anaconda environment on my machine (Linux Mint 18.1, yes I know its ancient..)
So after a while of fiddling around with it I thought it was the easiest to just plain clean install Anaconda from scratch. But here is where my problems begin:
I have specific version requirements for my CUDA to be 9.0 or 9.1 and the program I am trying to compile (using cython) was running on it just fine.
It also uses medpy, and also that has been running fine.
But now, when I try to install medpy, it just gives me the following:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata 
source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: |
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versionsThe following specifications were found to 
be incompatible with your CUDA driver:


  - feature:/linux-64::__cuda==9.1=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__cuda==9.1=0

Your installed CUDA driver is: 9.1
```

This is on a fresh environment after installing Anaconda3 version 4.8.3
then

```
conda create -n py36 python=3.6.8
conda activate py36
conda install -c bioconda medpy
```

I am really at a loss here. I don't understand why it doesn't show me which packages are the problem. Can anyone help?
Additionally I found that the anaconda comes with a `Python 3.8` instance, that I don't need. By default it replaces all imports of `cython`, even when I try to install `cython` in my `py36` environment (I am using cmake to build the project). I have a hunch that those problems are related to each other...

Comment: you can create another anaconda venv using python version of ur choice https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html

Comment: I thought I did that already when I specified pyton=3.6.8 when creating the environment. Is that different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my problems by using `pip3 install medpy` instead of trying to install with `conda`. Not sure if the version is different there, but it works now.

https://pypi.org/project/MedPy/

Hope this will help someone not bang their head against their desk in the future :)